# Can't airdrop to multiple addresses because of division truncation to zero

Tags: solidity, airdrop

I'm building airdrop smart contract on remixIDE. I want to send airdropToken which depends on how many stakeTokens that user has. When I add a single user, the contract works and user gets the airdropToken. But when I add multiple users, it doesn't work. The outcomes of airdropToken and airdropTokenList only keep showing 0.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.17;


contract Airdrop is Ownable{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    //Vairables
    uint256 BIGNUMBER = 10**18;
    uint256 totalAirdropToken = 10000; 

    address public owner;
    IERC20 public airdropToken;

    uint256 public totalStakeToken; //total of user's stakeToken
    address[] public receiverList; //list of users which owner added
    uint256[] public airdropTokenList; //list of tokens the user will receive
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakeTokens; //user's address -> user's stakeToken
    mapping(address => uint256) public airdropTokens; //user's address -> user's airdropToken

    //Contructor
    constructor(address _airdropTokenAddr) public {
      owner = msg.sender;
      airdropToken = IERC20(_airdropTokenAddr);
    }
    
    //Event
    event Drop(address account, uint256 amount);

    //A function that calculate tokens to give to a user
    function calculate(address _account) private view returns(uint256) {
      return (stakeTokens[_account]).div(totalStakeToken).mul(totalAirdropToken).mul(BIGNUMBER);
    }

    //owner saves user's address and their amount of stakeToken
    function saveUserTokens(address[] memory _recipients, uint256[] memory _amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(_recipients.length == _amount.length);
        receiverList = _recipients;

        for (uint i = 0; i < receiverList.length; i++) {
            require(_recipients[i] != address(0));
            totalStakeToken += _amount[i];
            stakeTokens[receiverList[i]] = _amount[i];
        }
    }

    //owner saves the calculated airdropToken to mapping(airdropTokens)
    function sendAirdropToken() public onlyOwner {
      for(uint i=0; i<receiverList.length; i++){
          airdropTokenList.push(calculate(receiverList[i]));
          airdropTokens[receiverList[i]] = calculate(receiverList[i]);
      }
    }

    //user can get the airdropToken by calling this function
    function drop() public {
      IERC20(airdropToken).transfer(msg.sender, airdropTokens[msg.sender]);

      emit Drop(msg.sender, airdropTokens[msg.sender]);
    }

    function destroy() public onlyOwner {
      IERC20(airdropToken).transfer(msg.sender, IERC20(airdropToken).balanceOf(address(this)));

      selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }

    function airdropOwnerBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
      return IERC20(airdropToken).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function airdropUserBalance(address _account) public view returns (uint256) {
      return IERC20(airdropToken).balanceOf(_account);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi librete! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you add more details? like what functions are called?, what's the error?, how the functions are called?, which token are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using ERC20 as airdropToken/stakeToken. I just add some description of function and my contract. What I want to know is why the airdropToken is not calculated and mapping(airdropTokens) gives me 0 when I added two or more users to saveUserTokens function. I mean user can get their calculated airdropToken when I added a single user to saveUserTokens function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `calculate` function

```
(stakeTokens[_account]).div(totalStakeToken).mul(totalAirdropToken).mul(BIGNUMBER)
```

If `totalStakeToken > stakeTokens[_account]` is true then `(stakeTokens[_account]).div(totalStakeToken)` will be zero because of the integer division truncation.

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
(stakeTokens[_account]).mul(totalAirdropToken).mul(BIGNUMBER).div(totalStakeToken)
```